# Solve 4 equations with a parameter using matrices

Tags: matrices, matrix-equations

Find for what values of the parameter $k$ there are:

1. A single solution.
2. Infinite solutions.
3. No solutions.

$x_1 +x_2 +2x_4 = 1 $

$x_1 +2x_2 +2x_3 +2x_4 = 3$

$x_1 +2x_2 +4x_3 +(2-k)x_4 = 3$

$x_1 +x_2 +(k+3)x_4 = k^2$

I put all these equations in a matrix and made it canonical

$\left( \begin{matrix}1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & k^3-2k^2-3k+5 \\ 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & -k^3+3k+2\\ 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & \frac{k^3-3k}{2} \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & k^2-3\end{matrix}\right)$

What do I do now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't go all the way down to reduced row echelon, because you may be dividing by zero depending on what $k$ is. So I reduced it down to\begin{bmatrix}
    1 & 1&0&2&1\\
   0&1&2&0&2\\
0&0&2&-k&0\\
0&0&0&k+1&k^2-1
\end{bmatrix}

Now from here it should be easy to see for what values of $k$ you have solutions.

Comment: I don't think I divided by 0 anywhere along the way.  I wrote all the steps I did and not a single time I divided by anything with $k$ in it. Anyway, I got the a mtrix containing $0,1,0,k+1,k^2-1$ in the bottom row. I'm not sure how to eliminate $x_2$ there.

Comment: @Pilpel If you do $R_4 \to R_4 - R_1$ you get my bottom row.

Comment: Ok I get $x_4(k+1) = k^2-1$. Can you help now?

Comment: @Pilpel Well from here, what makes the bottom row zero? (infinite solutions) What makes the left $k+1=0$ but $k^2-1 \neq 0$ (no solution), and what values of $k$ makes $k+1\neq 0$ and $k^2-1\neq 0$. (unique solution)

Comment: I get it. Thanks!

Comment: One more question, you say I know when the whole system has solution/s just from looking at the bottom row? Are you sure I don't need to check the other rows too?

Comment: @Pilpel There is only one other row with a $k$ in it, and it doesn't affect whether the solution exists or not. We are trying to create a free variable for infinite solutions, a contradiction for no solution, and exactly one solution is trivial.